# Type Mismatch In VBScript

Tags: function, vbscript

I have a function with 2 parameter inputs, the function does some logic and then assigns a `True` or `False` value to it's output (the function name).  I can see that the function logic is working correctly through `MsgBox` outputs, however it seems to not be assigning the value to the variable correctly.

Here's a snippet of what's happening:

From earlier in my code:

```
If FunctionName(x,y) = 1 Then
    MsgBox = "It's happening!"
```

Which is not returning 1 for some reason.  The function itself looks like this:

```
MsgBox "Found a match!"

delete = 1

MsgBox "Delete value is: " + CInt(delete)

FunctionName = delete
```

When I run this, I get the "Found a match!" message and then immediately get a "Type mismatch error" on the 2nd `MsgBox` line and it appears that the delete value is just empty.  I tried adding the `CInt` conversion as I read that may be the problem, but it didn't make a difference.

Any thoughts on this?

**Edit:**  Woo, changing the `+` to `&` worked for spitting out the `MsgBox` with `delete = 1`!  I am still having some issues getting that 1 value to trigger my original `If` statement that calls the function, though.

Comment: Can you please post all of the code?

Comment: Yes, have updated with more details.

Comment: You're getting the error, because the `+` operator does different things for strings (concatenation) and integers (addition), so the VBScript interpreter doesn't know what to do when you "add" an integer to a string. Using `CInt` just cemented the issue. The code would've worked had you either used `CStr` instead of `CInt` or the string concatenation operator (`&`) instead of `+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate strings, use the `&`.

Like this:

```
MsgBox "Found a match!"
delete = 1
MsgBox "Delete value is: " & delete
```

Comment: Hey thanks!  This worked great for my 2nd MsgBox and i can see that delete is indeed equal to 1.  I'm having a problem returning this from the function that contains it though...

The next line after MsgBox is basically:
    FunctionName = delete
But i am not getting the 1 back in the spot where i originally call the Function (an If Statement) for some reason